# Combining Two Columns in R into one long column

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R that has multiple columns which I need to all be in the same column.

Here is a sample dataset

```
   Net1  Net2  Net3  Net4  Net5  Net6  Net7  Net8  Net9 Net10 Net11 Net12
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
1   -18   -30    22    27    16    47   -31    53   -10    NA NA    NA   
2    -9    53     5   -38    -3   -46    48    19   -47   -27 NA    NA
```

Essentially the columns are all groups of the same thing. Net1+Net5+Net9 are all representing the same thing so I would need them in one column. Same thing for Net2+Net6+Net10. Net3+Net7+Net11. Finally Net4+Net8+Net12.

So instead of their being 12 columns their should just be 4 in the new dataframe. With this being the desired output:

```
   Net1  Net2  Net3  Net4  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
1   -18   -30    22    27    
2    16    47    -31   53    
3   -10    NA    NA    NA    
4    -9    53     5   -38    
5    -3    -46    48   19    
6    -47  -27     NA   NA
```

Comment: Google "reshape from wide to long".  One R package that does this is `tidyr`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyr)

names(df) <- rep(c("Net1", "Net2", "Net3", "Net4"), 3L)
df %>% pivot_longer(everything(), ".value")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
   Net1  Net2  Net3  Net4
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1   -18   -30    22    27
2    16    47   -31    53
3   -10    NA    NA    NA
4    -9    53     5   -38
5    -3   -46    48    19
6   -47   -27    NA    NA
```

---

Or put everything in a pipeline if you want

```
df %>% 
  setNames(rep(c("Net1", "Net2", "Net3", "Net4"), 3L)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), ".value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a no-frills approach:

```
col_mat = matrix(1:12, nrow = 4)
col_mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    5    9
# [2,]    2    6   10
# [3,]    3    7   11
# [4,]    4    8   12

result = as.data.frame(apply(col_mat, 1, function(x) unlist(df[x])))
names(result) = names(df)[col_mat[, 1]]
result
#   Net1 Net2 Net3 Net4
# 1  -18  -30   22   27
# 2   -9   53    5  -38
# 3   16   47  -31   53
# 4   -3  -46   48   19
# 5  -10   NA   NA   NA
# 6  -47  -27   NA   NA
```

I'm using this sample data - you may need to convert your logical columns to numeric first.

```
   df = read.table(text = 'Net1  Net2  Net3  Net4  Net5  Net6  Net7  Net8  Net9 Net10 Net11 Net12
1   -18   -30    22    27    16    47   -31    53   -10    NA NA    NA   
2    -9    53     5   -38    -3   -46    48    19   -47   -27 NA    NA  ', header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  group_by(row = ceiling(row_number()/4)) %>%
  mutate(name = paste0('Net', 1:4)) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-row)

#   Net1  Net2  Net3  Net4
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1   -18   -30    22    27
#2    16    47   -31    53
#3   -10    NA    NA    NA
#4    -9    53     5   -38
#5    -3   -46    48    19
#6   -47   -27    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward base R approach:

```
data.frame(matrix(t(df), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, names(df)[1:4])))
#   Net1 Net2 Net3 Net4
# 1  -18  -30   22   27
# 2   16   47  -31   53
# 3  -10   NA   NA   NA
# 4   -9   53    5  -38
# 5   -3  -46   48   19
# 6  -47  -27   NA   NA
```